# Coldfusion moving JSON files to a folder breaks the page (relative path)

Tags: file, path, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

my first question. Please feel free to yell if I need to learn something. I have been all over this site, adobe as well, internets. I think my question is so basic that nobody has ever asked it. My specialty is VBA/Excel/SQL and I am a 100% noob re: CF & general web coding so there's that. But I am trying really hard.

I have been tasked with maintaining/updating a web app running on CF 2016 version. First task was to update the existing charts that broke when moving from CF11 to the new version. I did so with JSON files as per zingcharts, and when the JSON files live in the same directory as the .cfm file for the page, the charts show up fine. Beautiful. Best charts ever probably. So that part is working.

Here is how the folder structure looks where I access all the CF files:

D:\Websites\dev\pages\~cfm & json files~

This is how I have it set up now to grab the JSON files into the style variable names:

```
    <!--- set JSON files for chart data--->
    <cfset dataDirectory = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())/>
    and then:
    <cfset bargraph.JSON=deserializeJSON(fileRead("#dataDirectory#bargraph.json"))>
```

Of course, the folder with the .cfm files in it is getting crowded. So I made a JSON folder in the same level, thinking I would like my structure to look like:

D:\Websites\dev\pages\json\

So I changed my thing to:

```
    <cfset dataDirectory = getDirectoryFromPath(#ExpandPath( "../json/" )#)/>
```

And received this error:

D:\Websites\dev\json\bargraph.json (The system cannot find the path specified)

One directory too high. So I changed it to:

```
    <cfset dataDirectory = getDirectoryFromPath(#ExpandPath( "./json/" )#)/>
```

No more file not found error, but the page stops loading when it gets to the end of all the JSON "cfset" statements.

What in tarnation am I missing? Thank you all in advance. You have helped me so so many times over the years.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment than a question, but here goes.

You have a page at:

`D:\Websites\dev\pages\mypage.cfm`

And you are trying to get a JSON file at

`D:\Websites\dev\pages\json\bargraph.json`

Have you tried to the path from

```
dataDirectory =  GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()) & "json/";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. It appears to work the same as before. No file not found error, but the page still stops loading after the variables are set. UGH. Thanks again!

Comment: The page stops loading. Hmm. Try putting in some dummy content before and after the set statements. To see if it really stops. ALSO consider having a variable in `application.cfc` that always knows where it is. Then base everything off of the the application wide variable.